# Email is not send in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working with **CakePHP version 1.3.13.**

Here, I want to send mail. So I have written code like this :

```
function send_mail_to_client()
{
     $text = "sending mail";
     App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
     $Email = new CakeEmail();
     $Email->from(array('sachingarala.v2047@gmail.com' => 'My Site'));
     $Email->to('nisargbhavsar24@gmail.com');
     $Email->subject('Test mail');
     $Email->send($text);
}
```

But, mail is not send to the destination. So what is the wrong in this code?
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have email config their?

Answer (score 0):

Add the configs after initialization i.e. `$Email = new CakeEmail();`  like

```
$Email->config(array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

Comment: is there any way to send email without smtp configuration?

Comment: @Nisarg I think its not there, not for localhost, on live server `mail()` might work. With cakephp not possible